# On scroll, particles are not pointing at the right point

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles

I am looking for a solution for my [website's](http://speedycart.tk/clgproj/home.jsp) particles pointing problem. When I am using this on particle.js (or own custom.js) `interactivity:{detect_on:"window",..` , on scrolling the mouse pointer is locating another place, but when I am using `interactivity:{detect_on:"canvas",` it's working fine, the pointer locating at the right place inside of canvas.

```js
/* particles.js variables with default values */
 
 var pJS=function(e,t){var a=document.querySelector("#"+e+" > .particles-js-canvas-el");this.pJS={canvas:{el:a,w:a.offsetWidth,h:a.offsetHeight},particles:{number:{value:400,density:{enable:!0,value_area:800}},color:{value:"#fff"},shape:{type:"circle",stroke:{width:0,color:"#ff0000"},polygon:{nb_sides:5},image:{src:"",width:100,height:100}},opacity:{value:1,random:!1,anim:{enable:!1,speed:2,opacity_min:0,sync:!1}},size:{value:20,random:!1,anim:{enable:!1,speed:20,size_min:0,sync:!1}},line_linked:{enable:!0,distance:100,color:"#fff",opacity:1,width:1},move:{enable:!0,speed:2,direction:"none",random:!1,straight:!1,out_mode:"out",bounce:!1,attract:{enable:!1,rotateX:3e3,rotateY:3e3}},array:[]},interactivity:{detect_on:"canvas",events:{onhover:{enable:!0,mode:"grab"},onclick:{enable:!0,mode:"push"},resize:!0},modes:{grab:{distance:100,line_linked:{opacity:1}},bubble:{distance:100,size:80,duration:.4},repulse:{distance:100,duration:.4},push:{particles_nb:4},remove:{particles_nb:2}},mouse:{}},retina_detect:!1,fn:{interact:{},modes:{},vendors:{}},tmp:{}};var i=this.pJS;t&&Object.deepExtend(i,t),i.tmp.obj={size_value:i.particles.size.value,size_anim_speed:i.particles.size.anim.speed,move_speed:i.particles.move.speed,line_linked_distance:i.particles.line_linked.distance,line_linked_width:i.particles.line_linked.width,mode_grab_distance:i.interactivity.modes.grab.distance,mode_bubble_distance:i.interactivity.modes.bubble.distance,mode_bubble_size:i.interactivity.modes.bubble.size,mode_repulse_distance:i.interactivity.modes.repulse.distance},i.fn.retinaInit=function(){i.retina_detect&&window.devicePixelRatio>1?(i.canvas.pxratio=window.devicePixelRatio,i.tmp.retina=!0):(i.canvas.pxratio=1,i.tmp.retina=!1),i.canvas.w=i.canvas.el.offsetWidth*i.canvas.pxratio,i.canvas.h=i.canvas.el.offsetHeight*i.canvas.pxratio,i.particles.size.value=i.tmp.obj.size_value*i.canvas.pxratio,i.particles.size.anim.speed=i.tmp.obj.size_anim_speed*i.canvas.pxratio,i.particles.move.speed=i.tmp.obj.move_speed*i.canvas.pxratio,i.particles.line_linked.distance=i.tmp.obj.line_linked_distance*i.canvas.pxratio,i.interactivity.modes.grab.distance=i.tmp.obj.mode_grab_distance*i.canvas.pxratio,i.interactivity.modes.bubble.distance=i.tmp.obj.mode_bubble_distance*i.canvas.pxratio,i.particles.line_linked.width=i.tmp.obj.line_linked_width*i.canvas.pxratio,i.interactivity.modes.bubble.size=i.tmp.obj.mode_bubble_size*i.canvas.pxratio,i.interactivity.modes.repulse.distance=i.tmp.obj.mode_repulse_distance*i.canvas.pxratio},i.fn.canvasInit=function(){i.canvas.ctx=i.canvas.el.getContext("2d")},i.fn.canvasSize=function(){i.canvas.el.width=i.canvas.w,i.canvas.el.height=i.canvas.h,i&&i.interactivity.events.resize&&window.addEventListener("resize",function(){i.canvas.w=i.canvas.el.offsetWidth,i.canvas.h=i.canvas.el.offsetHeight,i.tmp.retina&&(i.canvas.w*=i.canvas.pxratio,i.canvas.h*=i.canvas.pxratio),i.canvas.el.width=i.canvas.w,i.canvas.el.height=i.canvas.h,i.particles.move.enable||(i.fn.particlesEmpty(),i.fn.particlesCreate(),i.fn.particlesDraw(),i.fn.vendors.densityAutoParticles()),i.fn.vendors.densityAutoParticles()})},i.fn.canvasPaint=function(){i.canvas.ctx.fillRect(0,0,i.canvas.w,i.canvas.h)},i.fn.canvasClear=function(){i.canvas.ctx.clearRect(0,0,i.canvas.w,i.canvas.h)},i.fn.particle=function(e,t,a){if(this.radius=(i.particles.size.random?Math.random():1)*i.particles.size.value,i.particles.size.anim.enable&&(this.size_status=!1,this.vs=i.particles.size.anim.speed/100,i.particles.size.anim.sync||(this.vs=this.vs*Math.random())),this.x=a?a.x:Math.random()*i.canvas.w,this.y=a?a.y:Math.random()*i.canvas.h,this.x>i.canvas.w-2*this.radius?this.x=this.x-this.radius:this.x<2*this.radius&&(this.x=this.x+this.radius),this.y>i.canvas.h-2*this.radius?this.y=this.y-this.radius:this.y<2*this.radius&&(this.y=this.y+this.radius),i.particles.move.bounce&&i.fn.vendors.checkOverlap(this,a),this.color={},"object"==typeof e.value)if(e.value instanceof Array){var s=e.value[Math.floor(Math.random()*i.particles.color.value.length)];this.color.rgb=hexToRgb(s)}else void 0!=e.value.r&&void 0!=e.value.g&&void 0!=e.value.b&&(this.color.rgb={r:e.value.r,g:e.value.g,b:e.value.b}),void 0!=e.value.h&&void 0!=e.value.s&&void 0!=e.value.l&&(this.color.hsl={h:e.value.h,s:e.value.s,l:e.value.l});else"random"==e.value?this.color.rgb={r:Math.floor(256*Math.random())+0,g:Math.floor(256*Math.random())+0,b:Math.floor(256*Math.random())+0}:"string"==typeof e.value&&(this.color=e,this.color.rgb=hexToRgb(this.color.value));this.opacity=(i.particles.opacity.random?Math.random():1)*i.particles.opacity.value,i.particles.opacity.anim.enable&&(this.opacity_status=!1,this.vo=i.particles.opacity.anim.speed/100,i.particles.opacity.anim.sync||(this.vo=this.vo*Math.random()));var n={};switch(i.particles.move.direction){case"top":n={x:0,y:-1};break;case"top-right":n={x:.5,y:-.5};break;case"right":n={x:1,y:-0};break;case"bottom-right":n={x:.5,y:.5};break;case"bottom":n={x:0,y:1};break;case"bottom-left":n={x:-.5,y:1};break;case"left":n={x:-1,y:0};break;case"top-left":n={x:-.5,y:-.5};break;default:n={x:0,y:0}}i.particles.move.straight?(this.vx=n.x,this.vy=n.y,i.particles.move.random&&(this.vx=this.vx*Math.random(),this.vy=this.vy*Math.random())):(this.vx=n.x+Math.random()-.5,this.vy=n.y+Math.random()-.5),this.vx_i=this.vx,this.vy_i=this.vy;var r=i.particles.shape.type;if("object"==typeof r){if(r instanceof Array){var c=r[Math.floor(Math.random()*r.length)];this.shape=c}}else this.shape=r;if("image"==this.shape){var o=i.particles.shape;this.img={src:o.image.src,ratio:o.image.width/o.image.height},this.img.ratio||(this.img.ratio=1),"svg"==i.tmp.img_type&&void 0!=i.tmp.source_svg&&(i.fn.vendors.createSvgImg(this),i.tmp.pushing&&(this.img.loaded=!1))}},i.fn.particle.prototype.draw=function(){var e=this;if(void 0!=e.radius_bubble)var t=e.radius_bubble;else t=e.radius;if(void 0!=e.opacity_bubble)var a=e.opacity_bubble;else a=e.opacity;if(e.color.rgb)var s="rgba("+e.color.rgb.r+","+e.color.rgb.g+","+e.color.rgb.b+","+a+")";else s="hsla("+e.color.hsl.h+","+e.color.hsl.s+"%,"+e.color.hsl.l+"%,"+a+")";switch(i.canvas.ctx.fillStyle=s,i.canvas.ctx.beginPath(),e.shape){case"circle":i.canvas.ctx.arc(e.x,e.y,t,0,2*Math.PI,!1);break;case"edge":i.canvas.ctx.rect(e.x-t,e.y-t,2*t,2*t);break;case"triangle":i.fn.vendors.drawShape(i.canvas.ctx,e.x-t,e.y+t/1.66,2*t,3,2);break;case"polygon":i.fn.vendors.drawShape(i.canvas.ctx,e.x-t/(i.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides/3.5),e.y-t/.76,2.66*t/(i.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides/3),i.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides,1);break;case"star":i.fn.vendors.drawShape(i.canvas.ctx,e.x-2*t/(i.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides/4),e.y-t/1.52,2*t*2.66/(i.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides/3),i.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides,2);break;case"image":;if("svg"==i.tmp.img_type)var n=e.img.obj;else n=i.tmp.img_obj;n&&i.canvas.ctx.drawImage(n,e.x-t,e.y-t,2*t,2*t/e.img.ratio)}i.canvas.ctx.closePath(),i.particles.shape.stroke.width>0&&(i.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle=i.particles.shape.stroke.color,i.canvas.ctx.lineWidth=i.particles.shape.stroke.width,i.canvas.ctx.stroke()),i.canvas.ctx.fill()},i.fn.particlesCreate=function(){for(var e=0;e<i.particles.number.value;e++)i.particles.array.push(new i.fn.particle(i.particles.color,i.particles.opacity.value))},i.fn.particlesUpdate=function(){for(var e=0;e<i.particles.array.length;e++){var t=i.particles.array[e];if(i.particles.move.enable){var a=i.particles.move.speed/2;t.x+=t.vx*a,t.y+=t.vy*a}if(i.particles.opacity.anim.enable&&(1==t.opacity_status?(t.opacity>=i.particles.opacity.value&&(t.opacity_status=!1),t.opacity+=t.vo):(t.opacity<=i.particles.opacity.anim.opacity_min&&(t.opacity_status=!0),t.opacity-=t.vo),t.opacity<0&&(t.opacity=0)),i.particles.size.anim.enable&&(1==t.size_status?(t.radius>=i.particles.size.value&&(t.size_status=!1),t.radius+=t.vs):(t.radius<=i.particles.size.anim.size_min&&(t.size_status=!0),t.radius-=t.vs),t.radius<0&&(t.radius=0)),"bounce"==i.particles.move.out_mode)var s={x_left:t.radius,x_right:i.canvas.w,y_top:t.radius,y_bottom:i.canvas.h};else s={x_left:-t.radius,x_right:i.canvas.w+t.radius,y_top:-t.radius,y_bottom:i.canvas.h+t.radius};switch(t.x-t.radius>i.canvas.w?(t.x=s.x_left,t.y=Math.random()*i.canvas.h):t.x+t.radius<0&&(t.x=s.x_right,t.y=Math.random()*i.canvas.h),t.y-t.radius>i.canvas.h?(t.y=s.y_top,t.x=Math.random()*i.canvas.w):t.y+t.radius<0&&(t.y=s.y_bottom,t.x=Math.random()*i.canvas.w),i.particles.move.out_mode){case"bounce":t.x+t.radius>i.canvas.w?t.vx=-t.vx:t.x-t.radius<0&&(t.vx=-t.vx),t.y+t.radius>i.canvas.h?t.vy=-t.vy:t.y-t.radius<0&&(t.vy=-t.vy)}if(isInArray("grab",i.interactivity.events.onhover.mode)&&i.fn.modes.grabParticle(t),(isInArray("bubble",i.interactivity.events.onhover.mode)||isInArray("bubble",i.interactivity.events.onclick.mode))&&i.fn.modes.bubbleParticle(t),(isInArray("repulse",i.interactivity.events.onhover.mode)||isInArray("repulse",i.interactivity.events.onclick.mode))&&i.fn.modes.repulseParticle(t),i.particles.line_linked.enable||i.particles.move.attract.enable)for(var n=e+1;n<i.particles.array.length;n++){var r=i.particles.array[n];i.particles.line_linked.enable&&i.fn.interact.linkParticles(t,r),i.particles.move.attract.enable&&i.fn.interact.attractParticles(t,r),i.particles.move.bounce&&i.fn.interact.bounceParticles(t,r)}}},i.fn.particlesDraw=function(){i.canvas.ctx.clearRect(0,0,i.canvas.w,i.canvas.h),i.fn.particlesUpdate();for(var e=0;e<i.particles.array.length;e++){i.particles.array[e].draw()}},i.fn.particlesEmpty=function(){i.particles.array=[]},i.fn.particlesRefresh=function(){cancelRequestAnimFrame(i.fn.checkAnimFrame),cancelRequestAnimFrame(i.fn.drawAnimFrame),i.tmp.source_svg=void 0,i.tmp.img_obj=void 0,i.tmp.count_svg=0,i.fn.particlesEmpty(),i.fn.canvasClear(),i.fn.vendors.start()},i.fn.interact.linkParticles=function(e,t){var a=e.x-t.x,s=e.y-t.y,n=Math.sqrt(a*a+s*s);if(n<=i.particles.line_linked.distance){var r=i.particles.line_linked.opacity-n/(1/i.particles.line_linked.opacity)/i.particles.line_linked.distance;if(r>0){var c=i.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line;i.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle="rgba("+c.r+","+c.g+","+c.b+","+r+")",i.canvas.ctx.lineWidth=i.particles.line_linked.width,i.canvas.ctx.beginPath(),i.canvas.ctx.moveTo(e.x,e.y),i.canvas.ctx.lineTo(t.x,t.y),i.canvas.ctx.stroke(),i.canvas.ctx.closePath()}}},i.fn.interact.attractParticles=function(e,t){var a=e.x-t.x,s=e.y-t.y;if(Math.sqrt(a*a+s*s)<=i.particles.line_linked.distance){var n=a/(1e3*i.particles.move.attract.rotateX),r=s/(1e3*i.particles.move.attract.rotateY);e.vx-=n,e.vy-=r,t.vx+=n,t.vy+=r}},i.fn.interact.bounceParticles=function(e,t){var a=e.x-t.x,i=e.y-t.y;Math.sqrt(a*a+i*i)<=e.radius+t.radius&&(e.vx=-e.vx,e.vy=-e.vy,t.vx=-t.vx,t.vy=-t.vy)},i.fn.modes.pushParticles=function(e,t){i.tmp.pushing=!0;for(var a=0;a<e;a++)i.particles.array.push(new i.fn.particle(i.particles.color,i.particles.opacity.value,{x:t?t.pos_x:Math.random()*i.canvas.w,y:t?t.pos_y:Math.random()*i.canvas.h})),a==e-1&&(i.particles.move.enable||i.fn.particlesDraw(),i.tmp.pushing=!1)},i.fn.modes.removeParticles=function(e){i.particles.array.splice(0,e),i.particles.move.enable||i.fn.particlesDraw()},i.fn.modes.bubbleParticle=function(e){if(i.interactivity.events.onhover.enable&&isInArray("bubble",i.interactivity.events.onhover.mode)){var t=e.x-i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,a=e.y-i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y,s=1-(l=Math.sqrt(t*t+a*a))/i.interactivity.modes.bubble.distance;function n(){e.opacity_bubble=e.opacity,e.radius_bubble=e.radius}if(l<=i.interactivity.modes.bubble.distance){if(s>=0&&"mousemove"==i.interactivity.status){if(i.interactivity.modes.bubble.size!=i.particles.size.value)if(i.interactivity.modes.bubble.size>i.particles.size.value){(c=e.radius+i.interactivity.modes.bubble.size*s)>=0&&(e.radius_bubble=c)}else{var r=e.radius-i.interactivity.modes.bubble.size,c=e.radius-r*s;e.radius_bubble=c>0?c:0}var o;if(i.interactivity.modes.bubble.opacity!=i.particles.opacity.value)if(i.interactivity.modes.bubble.opacity>i.particles.opacity.value)(o=i.interactivity.modes.bubble.opacity*s)>e.opacity&&o<=i.interactivity.modes.bubble.opacity&&(e.opacity_bubble=o);else(o=e.opacity-(i.particles.opacity.value-i.interactivity.modes.bubble.opacity)*s)<e.opacity&&o>=i.interactivity.modes.bubble.opacity&&(e.opacity_bubble=o)}}else n();"mouseleave"==i.interactivity.status&&n()}else if(i.interactivity.events.onclick.enable&&isInArray("bubble",i.interactivity.events.onclick.mode)){if(i.tmp.bubble_clicking){t=e.x-i.interactivity.mouse.click_pos_x,a=e.y-i.interactivity.mouse.click_pos_y;var l=Math.sqrt(t*t+a*a),v=((new Date).getTime()-i.interactivity.mouse.click_time)/1e3;v>i.interactivity.modes.bubble.duration&&(i.tmp.bubble_duration_end=!0),v>2*i.interactivity.modes.bubble.duration&&(i.tmp.bubble_clicking=!1,i.tmp.bubble_duration_end=!1)}function p(t,a,s,n,r){if(t!=a)if(i.tmp.bubble_duration_end)void 0!=s&&(o=t+(t-(n-v*(n-t)/i.interactivity.modes.bubble.duration)),"size"==r&&(e.radius_bubble=o),"opacity"==r&&(e.opacity_bubble=o));else if(l<=i.interactivity.modes.bubble.distance){if(void 0!=s)var c=s;else c=n;if(c!=t){var o=n-v*(n-t)/i.interactivity.modes.bubble.duration;"size"==r&&(e.radius_bubble=o),"opacity"==r&&(e.opacity_bubble=o)}}else"size"==r&&(e.radius_bubble=void 0),"opacity"==r&&(e.opacity_bubble=void 0)}i.tmp.bubble_clicking&&(p(i.interactivity.modes.bubble.size,i.particles.size.value,e.radius_bubble,e.radius,"size"),p(i.interactivity.modes.bubble.opacity,i.particles.opacity.value,e.opacity_bubble,e.opacity,"opacity"))}},i.fn.modes.repulseParticle=function(e){if(i.interactivity.events.onhover.enable&&isInArray("repulse",i.interactivity.events.onhover.mode)&&"mousemove"==i.interactivity.status){var t=e.x-i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,a=e.y-i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y,s=Math.sqrt(t*t+a*a),n=t/s,r=a/s,c=clamp(1/(l=i.interactivity.modes.repulse.distance)*(-1*Math.pow(s/l,2)+1)*l*100,0,50),o={x:e.x+n*c,y:e.y+r*c};"bounce"==i.particles.move.out_mode?(o.x-e.radius>0&&o.x+e.radius<i.canvas.w&&(e.x=o.x),o.y-e.radius>0&&o.y+e.radius<i.canvas.h&&(e.y=o.y)):(e.x=o.x,e.y=o.y)}else if(i.interactivity.events.onclick.enable&&isInArray("repulse",i.interactivity.events.onclick.mode))if(i.tmp.repulse_finish||(i.tmp.repulse_count++,i.tmp.repulse_count==i.particles.array.length&&(i.tmp.repulse_finish=!0)),i.tmp.repulse_clicking){var l=Math.pow(i.interactivity.modes.repulse.distance/6,3),v=i.interactivity.mouse.click_pos_x-e.x,p=i.interactivity.mouse.click_pos_y-e.y,d=v*v+p*p,m=-l/d*1;d<=l&&function(){var t=Math.atan2(p,v);if(e.vx=m*Math.cos(t),e.vy=m*Math.sin(t),"bounce"==i.particles.move.out_mode){var a=e.x+e.vx,s=e.y+e.vy;a+e.radius>i.canvas.w?e.vx=-e.vx:a-e.radius<0&&(e.vx=-e.vx),s+e.radius>i.canvas.h?e.vy=-e.vy:s-e.radius<0&&(e.vy=-e.vy)}}()}else 0==i.tmp.repulse_clicking&&(e.vx=e.vx_i,e.vy=e.vy_i)},i.fn.modes.grabParticle=function(e){if(i.interactivity.events.onhover.enable&&"mousemove"==i.interactivity.status){var t=e.x-i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,a=e.y-i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y,s=Math.sqrt(t*t+a*a);if(s<=i.interactivity.modes.grab.distance){var n=i.interactivity.modes.grab.line_linked.opacity-s/(1/i.interactivity.modes.grab.line_linked.opacity)/i.interactivity.modes.grab.distance;if(n>0){var r=i.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line;i.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle="rgba("+r.r+","+r.g+","+r.b+","+n+")",i.canvas.ctx.lineWidth=i.particles.line_linked.width,i.canvas.ctx.beginPath(),i.canvas.ctx.moveTo(e.x,e.y),i.canvas.ctx.lineTo(i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y),i.canvas.ctx.stroke(),i.canvas.ctx.closePath()}}}},i.fn.vendors.eventsListeners=function(){"window"==i.interactivity.detect_on?i.interactivity.el=window:i.interactivity.el=i.canvas.el,(i.interactivity.events.onhover.enable||i.interactivity.events.onclick.enable)&&(i.interactivity.el.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){if(i.interactivity.el==window)var t=e.clientX,a=e.clientY;else t=e.offsetX||e.clientX,a=e.offsetY||e.clientY;i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x=t,i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y=a,i.tmp.retina&&(i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x*=i.canvas.pxratio,i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y*=i.canvas.pxratio),i.interactivity.status="mousemove"}),i.interactivity.el.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(e){i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x=null,i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y=null,i.interactivity.status="mouseleave"})),i.interactivity.events.onclick.enable&&i.interactivity.el.addEventListener("click",function(){if(i.interactivity.mouse.click_pos_x=i.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,i.interactivity.mouse.click_pos_y=i.interactivity.mouse.pos_y,i.interactivity.mouse.click_time=(new Date).getTime(),i.interactivity.events.onclick.enable)switch(i.interactivity.events.onclick.mode){case"push":i.particles.move.enable?i.fn.modes.pushParticles(i.interactivity.modes.push.particles_nb,i.interactivity.mouse):1==i.interactivity.modes.push.particles_nb?i.fn.modes.pushParticles(i.interactivity.modes.push.particles_nb,i.interactivity.mouse):i.interactivity.modes.push.particles_nb>1&&i.fn.modes.pushParticles(i.interactivity.modes.push.particles_nb);break;case"remove":i.fn.modes.removeParticles(i.interactivity.modes.remove.particles_nb);break;case"bubble":i.tmp.bubble_clicking=!0;break;case"repulse":i.tmp.repulse_clicking=!0,i.tmp.repulse_count=0,i.tmp.repulse_finish=!1,setTimeout(function(){i.tmp.repulse_clicking=!1},1e3*i.interactivity.modes.repulse.duration)}})},i.fn.vendors.densityAutoParticles=function(){if(i.particles.number.density.enable){var e=i.canvas.el.width*i.canvas.el.height/1e3;i.tmp.retina&&(e/=2*i.canvas.pxratio);var t=e*i.particles.number.value/i.particles.number.density.value_area,a=i.particles.array.length-t;a<0?i.fn.modes.pushParticles(Math.abs(a)):i.fn.modes.removeParticles(a)}},i.fn.vendors.checkOverlap=function(e,t){for(var a=0;a<i.particles.array.length;a++){var s=i.particles.array[a],n=e.x-s.x,r=e.y-s.y;Math.sqrt(n*n+r*r)<=e.radius+s.radius&&(e.x=t?t.x:Math.random()*i.canvas.w,e.y=t?t.y:Math.random()*i.canvas.h,i.fn.vendors.checkOverlap(e))}},i.fn.vendors.createSvgImg=function(e){var t=i.tmp.source_svg.replace(/#([0-9A-F]{3,6})/gi,function(t,a,i,s){if(e.color.rgb)var n="rgba("+e.color.rgb.r+","+e.color.rgb.g+","+e.color.rgb.b+","+e.opacity+")";else n="hsla("+e.color.hsl.h+","+e.color.hsl.s+"%,"+e.color.hsl.l+"%,"+e.opacity+")";return n}),a=new Blob([t],{type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),s=window.URL||window.webkitURL||window,n=s.createObjectURL(a),r=new Image;r.addEventListener("load",function(){e.img.obj=r,e.img.loaded=!0,s.revokeObjectURL(n),i.tmp.count_svg++}),r.src=n},i.fn.vendors.destroypJS=function(){cancelAnimationFrame(i.fn.drawAnimFrame),a.remove(),pJSDom=null},i.fn.vendors.drawShape=function(e,t,a,i,s,n){var r=s*n,c=s/n,o=180*(c-2)/c,l=Math.PI-Math.PI*o/180;e.save(),e.beginPath(),e.translate(t,a),e.moveTo(0,0);for(var v=0;v<r;v++)e.lineTo(i,0),e.translate(i,0),e.rotate(l);e.fill(),e.restore()},i.fn.vendors.exportImg=function(){window.open(i.canvas.el.toDataURL("image/png"),"_blank")},i.fn.vendors.loadImg=function(e){if(i.tmp.img_error=void 0,""!=i.particles.shape.image.src)if("svg"==e){var t=new XMLHttpRequest;t.open("GET",i.particles.shape.image.src),t.onreadystatechange=function(e){4==t.readyState&&(200==t.status?(i.tmp.source_svg=e.currentTarget.response,i.fn.vendors.checkBeforeDraw()):(console.log("Error pJS - Image not found"),i.tmp.img_error=!0))},t.send()}else{var a=new Image;a.addEventListener("load",function(){i.tmp.img_obj=a,i.fn.vendors.checkBeforeDraw()}),a.src=i.particles.shape.image.src}else console.log("Error pJS - No image.src"),i.tmp.img_error=!0},i.fn.vendors.draw=function(){"image"==i.particles.shape.type?"svg"==i.tmp.img_type?i.tmp.count_svg>=i.particles.number.value?(i.fn.particlesDraw(),i.particles.move.enable?i.fn.drawAnimFrame=requestAnimFrame(i.fn.vendors.draw):cancelRequestAnimFrame(i.fn.drawAnimFrame)):i.tmp.img_error||(i.fn.drawAnimFrame=requestAnimFrame(i.fn.vendors.draw)):void 0!=i.tmp.img_obj?(i.fn.particlesDraw(),i.particles.move.enable?i.fn.drawAnimFrame=requestAnimFrame(i.fn.vendors.draw):cancelRequestAnimFrame(i.fn.drawAnimFrame)):i.tmp.img_error||(i.fn.drawAnimFrame=requestAnimFrame(i.fn.vendors.draw)):(i.fn.particlesDraw(),i.particles.move.enable?i.fn.drawAnimFrame=requestAnimFrame(i.fn.vendors.draw):cancelRequestAnimFrame(i.fn.drawAnimFrame))},i.fn.vendors.checkBeforeDraw=function(){"image"==i.particles.shape.type?"svg"==i.tmp.img_type&&void 0==i.tmp.source_svg?i.tmp.checkAnimFrame=requestAnimFrame(check):(cancelRequestAnimFrame(i.tmp.checkAnimFrame),i.tmp.img_error||(i.fn.vendors.init(),i.fn.vendors.draw())):(i.fn.vendors.init(),i.fn.vendors.draw())},i.fn.vendors.init=function(){i.fn.retinaInit(),i.fn.canvasInit(),i.fn.canvasSize(),i.fn.canvasPaint(),i.fn.particlesCreate(),i.fn.vendors.densityAutoParticles(),i.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line=hexToRgb(i.particles.line_linked.color)},i.fn.vendors.start=function(){isInArray("image",i.particles.shape.type)?(i.tmp.img_type=i.particles.shape.image.src.substr(i.particles.shape.image.src.length-3),i.fn.vendors.loadImg(i.tmp.img_type)):i.fn.vendors.checkBeforeDraw()},i.fn.vendors.eventsListeners(),i.fn.vendors.start()};function hexToRgb(e){e=e.replace(/^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i,function(e,t,a,i){return t+t+a+a+i+i});var t=/^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(e);return t?{r:parseInt(t[1],16),g:parseInt(t[2],16),b:parseInt(t[3],16)}:null}function clamp(e,t,a){return Math.min(Math.max(e,t),a)}function isInArray(e,t){return t.indexOf(e)>-1}Object.deepExtend=function(e,t){for(var a in t)t[a]&&t[a].constructor&&t[a].constructor===Object?(e[a]=e[a]||{},arguments.callee(e[a],t[a])):e[a]=t[a];return e},window.requestAnimFrame=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(e){window.setTimeout(e,1e3/60)},window.cancelRequestAnimFrame=window.cancelAnimationFrame||window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame||window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame||window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame||clearTimeout,window.pJSDom=[],window.particlesJS=function(e,t){"string"!=typeof e&&(t=e,e="particles-js"),e||(e="particles-js");var a=document.getElementById(e),i="particles-js-canvas-el",s=a.getElementsByClassName(i);if(s.length)for(;s.length>0;)a.removeChild(s[0]);var n=document.createElement("canvas");n.className=i,n.style.width="100%",n.style.height="100%",null!=document.getElementById(e).appendChild(n)&&pJSDom.push(new pJS(e,t))},window.particlesJS.load=function(e,t,a){var i=new XMLHttpRequest;i.open("GET",t),i.onreadystatechange=function(t){if(4==i.readyState)if(200==i.status){var s=JSON.parse(t.currentTarget.response);window.particlesJS(e,s),a&&a()}else console.log("Error pJS - XMLHttpRequest status: "+i.status),console.log("Error pJS - File config not found")},i.send()};
 
 
/* cutom particle js part*/

particlesJS("particles-js",{particles:{number:{value:80,density:{enable:!0,value_area:800}},color:{value:["#ffffff","#1abc9c","#e74c3c","#e67e22","#f1c40f"]},shape:{type:"circle",stroke:{width:0,color:"#000000"},polygon:{nb_sides:5},image:{src:"img/github.svg",width:100,height:100}},opacity:{value:.5,random:!1,anim:{enable:!1,speed:1,opacity_min:.1,sync:!1}},size:{value:6,random:!0,anim:{enable:!1,speed:40,size_min:.1,sync:!1}},line_linked:{enable:!0,distance:150,color:"#ffffff",opacity:.4,width:1},move:{enable:!0,speed:6,direction:"none",random:!1,straight:!1,out_mode:"out",attract:{enable:!1,rotateX:600,rotateY:1200}}},interactivity:{detect_on:"window",events:{onhover:{enable:!0,mode:"grab"},onclick:{enable:!0,mode:"push"},resize:!0},modes:{grab:{distance:200,line_linked:{opacity:1}},bubble:{distance:400,size:40,duration:2,opacity:8,speed:3},repulse:{distance:200},push:{particles_nb:4},remove:{particles_nb:2}}},retina_detect:!0,config_demo:{hide_card:!1,background_color:"#b61924",background_image:"",background_position:"50% 50%",background_repeat:"no-repeat",background_size:"cover"}});
```

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;


}
#particles-js {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Hello everyone</h1>
<h4 align="justify"> This is a just example of what is happening on my <a href="http://speedycart.tk/clgproj/home.jsp">WEBSITE</a>.</h4>
<h4>Only the difference is <code>interactivity:{detect_on:<span style="color:red;">"window"</span>,</code> AND <code>interactivity:{detect_on:<span style="color:red;">"canvas"</span>,</code></h4>
<p align="justify">On particle-js when I am using <span style="color:red;">"WINDOW"</span>,the pointer is not locating proper place at particles on scrolling, But when I am using <span style="color:red;">"CANVAS"</span>, its locating state is fine.</p>
<p align="justify" style="background-color:red;color:white;" >Just scroll down and you will understand what is happening with the pointer and particles grab system for the scrolling.</p>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<p align="justify" style="background-color:pink;" >If you want to change WINDOW to CANVAS then use <code>CTRL+F</code> and search for "cutom particle js part"</p>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thank you , can you fix this? @halfer